# Metro Messagebox Show "No Overload for method 'Show' takes '5' arguments"

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro

I'm facing a problem when i was trying to show a MetroMessageBox i got this error message "No Overload for method 'Show' takes '5' arguments".

My code is in the following image.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYUt.png)

```
MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Message", "Header", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code and/or error messages (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Comment: Done. I added the code.

Comment: Take adavantage of Visual Studio's IntelliSense. IntelliSense should tell you what overloads of the Show method using which parameters are available. (Alternatively, you could also take a look at mahapps.metro source code repository to see what Show method overloads the MetroMessageBox class provides...)

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code into the question not an image per the rules. But the reason your code isn't working is because you're not calling Show on an instance of the class, you're calling it as if it were a static method.

My guess is that you intended to do this:

```
new MetroMessageBox().Show(this, "Message", "Header", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: There are two overloads on that method, one is in your screenshot (IWin32WindowOwner owner), what is the other one?

Also have you named your form MetroMessageBox too? Because there could be a naming conflict.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I was having the same problem, an the solution is to install the MetroModernUI NuGet package alongside with the Metro Framework package. After that the program compiles.

Answer (score 0):

As NibblyPig said it's probably a naming conflict, I am using the Metro UI from here [Github Link](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui) and it's working as it should, the `MetroMessageBox.Show()` has 10 overloads, try checking the form name or if there are missing libraries.